# Data isn't inserting into different tables from one form

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to submit data from one form into two different tables, but it is not submitting, my form contains on two parts one is model, i.e., when modal form submit then its data saves into one table and rest of other data into another table.

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'patient_fname' => 'required',
        'patient_lname' => 'required',
        'patient_email' => 'required',
        'patient_dob' => 'required',
        'patient_guardian' => 'required',
        'patient_gender' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'patient_name' => 'required',
        'patient_insurance' => 'required',
        'patient_insurance_id' => 'required',
        'patient_reason' => 'required',
        'patient_new' => 'required',
        'patient_contact_no' => 'required',
        'patient_message' => 'required',
    ]);

    $userdata = Userdata::create([
        Input::get('patient_fname'),
        Input::get('patient_lname'),
        Input::get('patient_email'),
        Input::get('patient_dob'),
        Input::get('patient_guardian'),
        Input::get('patient_gender')
    ]);

    $form = Form::create([
        Input::get('patient_name'),
        Input::get('patient_insurance'),
        Input::get('patient_insurance_id'),
        Input::get('patient_reason'),
        Input::get('patient_new'),
        Input::get('patient_contact_no'),
        Input::get('patient_message')
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

**form.php**

```php
protected $guarded = [];

protected $table = "forms";

protected $fillable=['patient_name', 
    'patient_insurance','patient_insurance_id', 'patient_reason', 
    'patient_new', 'patient_message'];

public function userdata()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Userdata');
}
```

**userdata.php**

```php
protected $fillable = ['patient_fname', 'patient_lname', 
    'patient_email', 'patient_dob', 'patient_guardian', 
    'patient_gender','user_id'];

public function form()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Form');
}
```

Comment: 1. Table names ??
2 . form.php & userdata.php are the model name ?

Comment: Are you getting an errors?

Comment: Don you save data only ??
From one form to 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is because you're not supplying a key for the values in your `create` method.

Also, `validate` will return an array of the validated properties so you can just use that instead of using `Input::get()`:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'patient_fname'        => 'required',
        'patient_lname'        => 'required',
        'patient_email'        => 'required',
        'patient_dob'          => 'required',
        'patient_guardian'     => 'required',
        'patient_gender'       => 'required',
        'user_id'              => 'required',
        'patient_name'         => 'required',
        'patient_insurance'    => 'required',
        'patient_insurance_id' => 'required',
        'patient_reason'       => 'required',
        'patient_new'          => 'required',
        'patient_contact_no'   => 'required',
        'patient_message'      => 'required',
    ]);

    $userdata = Userdata::create([
        'patient_fname'    => $data['patient_fname'],
        'patient_lname'    => $data['patient_lname'],
        'patient_email'    => $data['patient_email'],
        'patient_dob'      => $data['patient_dob'],
        'patient_guardian' => $data['patient_guardian'],
        'patient_gender'   => $data['patient_gender'],
    ]);

    $form = Form::create([
        'patient_name'         => $data['patient_name'],
        'patient_insurance'    => $data['patient_insurance'],
        'patient_insurance_id' => $data['patient_insurance_id'],
        'patient_reason'       => $data['patient_reason'],
        'patient_new'          => $data['patient_new'],
        'patient_contact_no'   => $data['patient_contact_no'],
        'patient_message'      => $data['patient_message'],
    ]);

    return back();
}
```